# Merging PHP program with Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules

I've a website developed in Drupal which has some nodes to allow user to fill and submit forms. The user is allowed to upload and open a pdf file on that form, I've done this in PHP. Now is it possible to merge/integrate/combine this PHP code or component with the Drupal work? If yes, how? Does I have to write custom module for this or what? If there are more than one ways, kindly list all. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to built an form in Drupal which allows you to upload files?

Comment: No the form is already there but only upload functionality is in raw PHP code which I want to combine with my drupal form.

Answer (score 0):

You can also upload a file by using extra fields. Just go to structure->contenttypes and select your content type. There you can add File fields. This way you don't need to built the upload functionality yourself.

http://drupal.org/node/1326976

Comment: I need not only to upload file but to view/open the pdf file also like in 4shared.com. Can this be done in drupal???

Comment: Yeah you can directly view/open the file that you've uploaded without refreshing the form

Comment: Do you mean that if I upload a .ppt or .pdf I will be able to view like as in 4shared.com or slideshare.com etc sites???

Comment: Like i said you can upload and view a file directly. Don't know exactly how flexible the view option is in 4shared.com or in slideshare.com.